# The amlignore file doesn't reduce the size of snapshot

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

To overcome [300MB snapshot size limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-save-write-experiment-files#storage-limits-of-experiment-snapshots) I created an .amlignore file in the root of my repository:

```
/*
!/root
```

The intention is to exclude everything except `/root` directory where all python code is. The size of the `root` directory is less than 1MB, still I get an error of exceeding snapshot limit size of 300MB. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in version [1.0.74 of azureml-sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/azure-machine-learning-release-notes#azure-machine-learning-sdk-for-python-v1074)